# Symbolic linking of client (Mac) directory to server (Linux) directory

Tags: linux, mac-osx, network-share, file-sharing, symbolic-link

How can I link a directory on a Mac to a remote directory on a Linux server? The Linux server has Samba and SSH available, and I can add other services if necessary

Answer (score 0):

I created /etc/fstab and put the line in

`{server}:/{share} /Users/{user}/{share} url automounted,url==cifs://guest@{server}/{share} 0 0`

I then made a symbolic link to where I wanted it in the FS referencing `/Users/{user}/{share}`